# Define axis dimensions manually in ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale

When creating figures using `ggplot2` in `R`, the options to finetune your plots seem to be endless. But one thing I didn't encounter yet, is the following: Is it possible to manually specify the length (i.e., dimensions) of the axes of a plot.

For example: let's take the `diamonds` dataset from `ggplot2`

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = diamonds) + 
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = cut))
```

[image]

**Question**

Is it possible to specify that the length, for example of the x-axis, should be 5cm?

I am aware that using ggsave the dimensions of the entire plot can be specified, but is it also possible to specify dimensions of axes?